# Predict the next values based on the given data in R

Tags: r, prediction, forecasting

I have a vector which represents violations in each year.How to predict the violations in the next years in R.

```
year <- c(190519, 223721, 235321, 101934)
```

Please help me out

Comment: You can't. There is not enough information to build a model, let alone a prediction model.

Comment: You'll need more data points and some predictors/explanatory variables if you're to achieve any prediction

Comment: You could also impose a model on the data, e.g. an [AR(p)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoregressive_model), [MA(q)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving-average_model) or even the collected [ARIMA(p,d,q)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoregressive_integrated_moving_average) model. Alternatively, more complex, a [state-space model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State-space_representation). These models require much more data and other assumptions, however.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To illustrate the comments made by akash87 and Dominic Comtols that it would be futile to predict with little information, here's a linear model method and visualisation with ggplot:

```
year<-c(190519 ,223721, 235321, 101934)
df <- data.frame(year=1:4, crime= year)
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df, aes(x=year, y=crime)) + 
       geom_point() + 
       geom_smooth(method="lm", fullrange=T) + 
       xlim(1,6)
```

[image]

As seen from the plot, the predicted value by extrapolating the linear model in Year 6 can be anyway within the gray area, i.e between -339737 and 537576. You're better off just guess...

Comment: It's a simple linear regression model plotted with the data where 190519 violations occur in year 1, 223721 violations in year 2, 235321 violations in year 3 and 101934 violations in year 4 (represented by the points). The regression line provide the best fit across the sparse data, while the gray area represented the 95% confidence interval for the regression model.

Comment: Please do not use regression to extrapolate and predict though. I did this just to illustrate how ridiculous it is to even attempt predicting with 4 data-points.

Comment: This is the standard library of R, right? Do you have a good documentation about ggplot? I only found about ggplot2...

Answer (score 2):

The dataset is too small for a reliable forecast, but you could try the following, just to illustrate a possibility on how *time series forecasts* could be obtained in principle:

```
year <- c(190519, 223721, 235321, 101934)
library(forecast)
yearforecasts <- HoltWinters(as.ts(year), beta=FALSE, gamma=FALSE)
yearforecasts2 <- forecast.HoltWinters(yearforecasts,h=1)
> yearforecasts2
#  Point Forecast    Lo 80    Hi 80    Lo 95    Hi 95
#5       190518.3 95821.09 285215.5 45691.42 335345.2
plot.forecast(yearforecasts2)
```

[image]

The forecast is inaccurate and has a large error margin due to the very small number of data points. As pointed out at the beginning of this answer and in the comments, more data is required for a useful forecast. For the same reason, it is not possible to forecast more than one year ahead with this method.